# How stylesheets for mobile device should be?

Tags: css, media-queries

How should the style sheet for mobile devices differ from the style sheet for desktops?

I have a sample of how my stylesheet for print version is:

Can anyone tell me how should the corresponding classes in the stylesheet for mobile device be?

```
h1 
{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'NeoTechAlt';
}
```

Above is my `h1` for desktop stylesheet. How should the corresponding mobile stylesheet `h1` be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to change between both platforms.

i.e. if you want to change the font-size to be bigger on mobile change only this attribute.

It's recommended to use also one common stylesheet for all platforms and for each platform you want to customize an overriding stylesheet. This way you don't have to re-write all css rules, and you can just add the relevant changes.

Example:

```
<LINK href="all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<LINK href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" type="text/css">
```

**all.css**

```
h1 { font-size: 18px; line-height: 22px; color: #000; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'NeoTechAlt'; }
```

**mobile.css**

```
h1 { font-size: 22px; line-height: 26px; }
```

Comment: I didn't quite get the "for each platform an overriding stylesheet."

Comment: by over-riding do you mean the classes which will be different just mention those along with their different values?

Comment: Exactly. there are a lot of rules identical between both platforms.
You don't have to re-write them all.